# Changed iOS App to use different schemas (dev, test, production) and uploading to iTunes connect thinks it’s a new app

Tags: ios, xcode

I added new schemas and config flies so I can change environments and when I go to archive and upload the app to iTunes connect it now thinks that schema is a different app. (Development shows up after archive is complete to upload) If fails to upload because it wants a new cert and the whole shebang. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Ensure that the Bundle ID and developer team are correct

Comment: AppStore connect identifies apps by their BundleId. that's why you see them as different apps